# Entry should not activated by default

Tags: saveentry

Would it be possible that when you create a new entry, it's not activated by default?

I know there is a "Draft" option...  But is there an option for this?

Best,
Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default entry status in your section settings.

Example: If I would set the German toggle to disabled, all entries added to German local will be disabled by default.

[image]

Comment: I can work with that :)  thx!